# Not able to delete extranet user from sitecore

Tags: sitecore

When I try to delete an extranet user from sitecore , error pop up shows

> The following users could not be deleted:
>
> extranet\pratik.wasnik@example.com
> Exception:
> Non-static method requires a target.

Can anyone help me in deleting this user ? this user is already unlocked.

Comment: What does the logs say?

Answer (score 0):

The user sitecore\pratikw is not an extranet user but a user in the Sitecore domain. Maybe you are logged in to sitecore as the user and that causes the issue?

Extranet users is named like this extranet\. You should probably look for extranet\pratikw

Comment: Jens , It is actually extranet\pratik.wasnik@example.com.

Comment: thank you for correcting, for sitecore\pratikw it is getting deleted without any problem ! but for extranet user , it is not getting deleted !

Comment: Hi Jens and Ahmed , please see following log entry :

Comment: 5844 03:43:43 ERROR User can not be deleted
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetException
Message: Non-static method requires a target.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)

Comment: at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)

Comment: at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.TryGetFieldOrPropertyValue(MemberExpression me, Object instance, Object& memberValue)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.TryEvaluatePath(Expression expression, ConstantExpression& constantExpression)at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.EvaluateParameter(Object[] arguments)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)

Comment: at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at Jordans.Web.UI.code.ExtendedProvider.JordansMembershipProvider.DeleteUser(String username, Boolean deleteAllRelatedData)
   at System.Web.Security.Membership.DeleteUser(String username)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.UserManager.Delete.Run(ClientPipelineArgs args)